# Place Picker is not working and disappears

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using place picker, actually I downloaded the project from [here](https://github.com/delaroy/LocationsGeofencing). And I tried it out. I want to work on geo fencing. but I am not finding the way to how to search location on map first. For this I came to know about the Place Picker. It is deprecated as of 1st January 2019, but it can still be used.

So I downloaded it. I have a project in google developer console, I created that project for my map in project. So I enabled places api, and used same API key

MY Problem: 
I used same API key but the Place picker shows and disappears. I created another API key but of no use.

I search this problem and got to know some common mistakes but I am not having those as this project is already well set up.  So I have no hint what is the problem and there is no log whatsoever.

In my Manifest you can see it here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.delaroystudios.locationgeo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA5-VuAgljw6b3IZiUXnrWGIyQ7vSTQlrA" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name="com.delaroystudios.locationgeo.MainActivity">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="com.delaroystudios.locationgeo.provider.PlaceContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.delaroystudios.locationgeo"
            android:exported="false"/>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

SO it looks cool and there seems to be no fault in it.

Please help me what could be the problem?

Comment: How do you include Places SDK in your gradle?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'

Comment: Thats in my dependency

Comment: So, you are using deprecated version of Places SDK for Android. Try to use the new version and follow docs at: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the Place Picker has been deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer be available after that date. Please note that the **old users** that used Places SDK for iOS/Android are the only one who **can still use the Place Picker** during the deprecation period. The use of Places SDK for both platforms are now through enabling [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) and does not support the use of Place Picker anymore.

Google is conducting a review on what drives the users to use the Place Picker, if you are interested, kindly add your answer in the form mentioned in this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/128304760).